# How to add value in a table using Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pycharm

The aim of this code is to select a file then add it to a table and in the next column it should display the file format. Example:

[File Name] [File Format]

[candy.csv] [a csv file]

[corona.txt] [a txt file]

[computer.json] [a json file]

I know how to select files and i know how to create a table, but I am having trouble to make the two work together. I am new to python.

This is the code to select all the files in a specific folder

```
def browse():
    os.chdir("/home/amel/Downloads/Corona")
    for file in glob.glob("*.*"):
        s = file
        print(s)
        folder_path = str(s)
        tx.insert(END, folder_path + '\n')


    return s
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `os` module to split pathfilename into components.

Taking your code snippet and expanding it to include a key binding `<Control-g>` that calls function `browse`.

This splits pathfilename into path, filename and then filename into name, ext.

filename and ext are inserted into `tk.Text` to produce an appropriate list.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import os, glob

root = tk.Tk()
tx = tk.Text()
tx.grid()

# select your own path
pathname = os.getcwd()

def browse(ev):

    os.chdir(pathname)
    for file in glob.glob("*.*"):
        path, filename = os.path.split(file)
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        tx.insert(tk.END, f"[{filename}] [{ext}]\n")

root.bind("<Control-g>", browse)
root.mainloop()
```